# Adding a XIB / NIB file to iOS after the fact

Tags: ios, load, nib

So initially I thought I wasn't going to need XIB files and can generate my view programatically with loadView, therefore, when I modeled out my classes, I decided not to create the XIB file.

Now I changed my mind and decided I DO want a xib file to my already created classes. So I previously had an HomeViewController.m/h files. In XCode, I went File--> New--> User Interface--> View, and created an HomeViewController.xib file.

In my App Delegate, I tried doing this:

```
HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = home;
```

I also tried this:

```
HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = home;
```

In both cases, I get a SIGABRT error. If I DON'T add the home UIViewController to the rootViewController, I get no error, but obviously nothing on screen.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your nib objects refer to other class..

In you xib file..in the **identity inspector**..make sure every object has the class name of **HomeViewController** .

Hope it helps.

Comment: This led me to the right path so I'm accepting your answer! For those who run into this, after you create your XIB, click on File's Owner, then in the Identity Inspector, as outlined, make sure the Custom Class refers to your class. Then click on the connections inspector (far right icon with an arrow), and control click on the 'view' outlet and drag it over to the View in the Objects panel. (it's weird this isn't done).

Answer (score 0):

Try just creating the `HomeViewController` in the XIB and link it in IB.  You can tell it to load the view from another XIB within IB there, and also set the default interface file in your project's properties